pandas to_csv adding extra escape character to path
I am generating a csv file in pandas using this code:
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
path2 = 'Documents'
current_datetime = datetime.now()
filename = f"python_df_{current_datetime}.csv"
full_path = os.path.join(current_working_directory, path2, filename)

when I print(full_path) I get the desired path, however when I run df.to_csv(full_path, index=False) I get the file with an extra \ as such 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\python_df_2024-07-23 16:07:08.01581.csv which leads to the following error:
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\python_df_2024-07-23 16:07:08.01581.csv'

Also, I'm using a Windows machine and whilst this works fine on mac I can't get it work on Windows.

You cannot use a : with Windows. See e.g. here. So, you could use something like datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").

If you really want to have a colon in the filename you could use the MODIFIER LETTER RAISED COLON \u02f8 instead, but I'm not saying that this is a good idea.
